# vueTemplate stop workoing in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```
import template from './edit-date-field.vue';
```

This code is stop working , How to make it work again in vue 3 ?

```
let vueTemplate: any = template;
let instance = new vueTemplate();
```

and this is how i call it from another component:

```
EditDateFieldInitializer.InitEditDateField(element, date, dateChangedCallback, onEditModeExit);
```

This is the full code of what i'm trying to do.
It's working great on vue 2 but not it's not working on vue 3

```
export default class EditTextFieldInitializer {
    public static InitEditTextField(config: EditTextFieldConfig) {
        debugger
        let vueTemplate: any = template;
        let instance = new vueTemplate();

        instance.$data.form.value = config.value;
        instance.$data.onValueChanged = config.onValueChanged;
        instance.$data.onEditModeExit = config.onEditModeExit;
        instance.$data.rules = config.validationRules;

        instance.$mount(config.element);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider reading up on the [composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html) and migrate this piece of code. By the looks of it, the composition API is designed specifically to meet the needs of scenarios like this.

Comment: I have to rewrite bunch of code to do that

Comment: all what i need is to access the data from the template and set the data

Comment: There are [a lot of breaking changes](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/introduction.html#breaking-changes) when migrating from Vue2 to Vue3 so... instead of trying to hack your code to make it work again, my original advice stands ;)